# No-IP Accessing Local Desktop Instead of Local Router Address

Tags: networking

I'm trying to get a local desktop computer accessible through a No-IP "hostname" which I set up. The local desktop computer is connected to a router with dynamic IP assigned to it. What would I need to get the "hostname" showing local desktop computer instead of showing the router control panel screen?

Local desktop is running digital signage server and needs to be accessible from outside the network. It is not technically a remote access but the media player outside local network has to be able to pull data from the local desktop. The local desktop is running Windows 10.

Hope that clarifies my question. Sorry for the confusion earlier. This is my first time using this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to access the web interface of your server (not RDP). If this is the case: On the router, you need to forward port 80 (http) and/or port 443 (https) to the "local desktop computer" (unless the server doesn't use the default ports for its web interface).

If you need to access your local computer via RDP you need to forward port 3389.